# Element implicitly has an any type because expression of type '0'can't be used to index type 'Object' - angular error

Tags: angular, typescript

Property '0' does not exist on type'Object'.ts(7053)
I am getting error where i have written data[0]. I was trying to retrieve data from php database

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-adashboard',
  templateUrl: './adashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adashboard.component.css']
})
export class AdashboardComponent {
  title = 'angulardatatables';
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  
  data = []  ;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/angular_admin/php/user.php').subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data[0];
    
   
    
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true
    };
}

}


Can anyone help me here ?
```

Comment: `data` is most probably an object and not an array, but you treat it like an array. Can you extend your question by adding the console-output of `data` ?  I mean: Can you show us what the `data`-object that gets returned from the php-backend looks like?

Comment: **this** is only to indicate to typescript that you "expect" an array: `subscribe((data:any[]) =>....)`, but be sure that your API return an array.